# bsddb3.db.DBRunRecoveryError

Tags: python, bsddb

I am using Python 2.7.2 and the bsddb3 module

I am just simple checking if the db contains an element, and if not then add it

For specific keys when I do a `.get(hashkey)` , then  I receive this error message:

```
bsddb3.db.DBRunRecoveryError: (-30975, 'DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery -- PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery')
```

the hashkey, which is an md5 is not special, looks similar to the ones which does not cause this problem

did anyone met with this before?

(Debian 6)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your database is corrupt. Try the [Berkeley DB recovery procedures](http://pybsddb.sourceforge.net/ref/transapp/recovery.html) on the file as the error message recommends.

Comment: Just noting that one of my users got this error message just now, and it didn't occur to them or me that the words "run recovery" were an instruction :) 

Nor do we know how to do that!   In my case bsddb is being used by shelve, which I am using, so I don't know anything about what this message means or how I would get a corrupted db, or how to recover it :(